# How do you pass secrets to the AWS Lambda function when making a request to it?

Tags: amazon-web-services

How do you pass secrets to a Lambda function when making a request to it?

I'm trying to set up a headless webshop with BigCommerce and have had to build a proxy using AWS Lambda functions and the AWS API Gateway to get around CORS. I need to pass sensitive data to them, like payment access tokens and credit card details, and I'm not sure how to do so securely. So far non-sensitive data has been passed through query string parameters. I'm guessing this isn't secure for sensitive data?

Apologies if this is vague, I'm a little at sea.

Comment: Maybe this link will give you an idea of how sensitive data like credit card is handled (In the artice, author uses stripe (payment service)). https://yos.io/2017/06/22/serverless-stripe/

Also i think lambda only works with https (secure), so sending data in the body would be fine. Read This answer as well https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51069/post-over-https-secure-enough-for-sensitive-data

Comment: If you're using HTTPS, which I assume you are, then query parameters are encrypted but, despite that, you should not send sensitive data this way (see http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/02/20/how-secure-are-query-strings-over-https/).